# Reactjs validation using Joi

Tags: javascript, reactjs, joi

The validation of JOI seems fine for me, scenario: when i tried to click submit without the value or selecting any categories it didnt submit and an error message appear, but when i tried to select **what i want is that the error message will disappear and when the user click submit again it will success**. thats the current behavior of this code, the Autocomplete is multiple selection

how can i achieve this : **what i want is that the error message will disappear and when the user click submit again it will success**??

```
export const VALIDATION_SCHEMA = {
  categories: Joi.array()
    .label('Categories')
    .items(
      Joi.object({
        name: Joi.string().required(),
        value: Joi.string().required(),
      }).required().messages({
        'string.empty': '"Categories" is invalid'
      }),
    ),
}
```

//

```
  const onHandleChangeInputCategories = (field, value) => {
    console.log(value) // please see below
    const _categories = value.map((name) => name)
    console.log("value: ", _categories)
    onHandleInputValidation(
      'categories',
      _categories);
  };

  const onHandleInputValidation = (field, value) => {
    try {
      Joi.assert(value, _.get(VALIDATION_SCHEMA, field));
      setFormError(_.omit(formError, field));
      return { error: false, valid: true };
    } catch (err) {
      return { error: err.message, valid: false };
    }
  };

<Autocomplete
     onChange={(event, value) => {
                onHandleChangeInputCategories('categories', value);
              }}
     renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
                  {...params}
                  label={'Categories'}
                  error={Boolean(formError.categories)}
                  sx={{
                    flexWrap: 'wrap',
                  }}
                  key="tf_categories"
           />
     )}

/>
<FormHelperText
      error={Boolean(formError.categories)}>
      {formError.categories}
</FormHelperText>
```

console result

[image]